# How to determine which version of HttpClient comes with Android SDK used?

Tags: android, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to use the testing classes for `HttpClient` (4.5.2) particularly `LocalTestServerBase` in an Android project. However, it keeps failing as it's looking for components in the core package. I can't add dependency to the core HttpClient because Android prevents it to avoid conflicts with the HttpClient built into Android itself. So, what I want to do now is to just define dependency to testing classes that match the version of HttpClient that comes with the Android platform I'm current using. How do I check which version of HttpClient a particular Android SDK uses?

Comment: Are you aware HttpClient is deprecated?

Comment: Do you mean in Android? Not with the version I'm using, it doesn't seem to be. I think it's Android 4 or 5.

Comment: Yes in android, the recommended built in class is now HttpURLConnection

Comment: I think that's true for 6, but I'm not using 6 yet.

Comment: But why write code now that may need to be replaced later when you could just use the recommended class now? http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: Because I'm working on an already existent code base that is using a previous version of Android. Also, does the latest Android version provide a way to mock calls to remote service via that new `HttpURLConnection` class?